# How to initialize and provide value to GridView boundfield , template and item template dynamically from code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I have this code in my aspx file for showing data coming from sql only providing datasource to this GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="CNIC" HeaderText ="CNIC"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="Name" HeaderText ="Name"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="FatherName" HeaderText ="Father Name"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="Gender" HeaderText ="Gender"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="DOB" HeaderText ="Date of birth"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="maritalStatus" HeaderText ="Marital Status"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="religion" HeaderText ="Religion"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="postalAddress" HeaderText ="Postal Address"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="permenantAddress" HeaderText ="Permenant Address"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="email" HeaderText ="Email Address"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="telephoneNumber" HeaderText ="Telephon Number"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="cellPhoneNumber" HeaderText ="Cellphone Number"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Photo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" Height="100px" Width="100px" ImageUrl ='<%#"data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("photo")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Image>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="passportNumber" HeaderText ="Passport Number"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="passportValidity" HeaderText ="Passport Validity"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="dualNationality" HeaderText ="Dual Nationality"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="nationality" HeaderText ="Nationality"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="nationalitySince" HeaderText ="Nationality since"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="policeVerification" HeaderText ="Police verification"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Signature">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image3" Height="100px" Width="100px" ImageUrl ='<%#"data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("piSignature")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Image>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This code is working fine, but I need to do it dynamically from code behind file.I just want this `<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>`in my aspx file and do all the rest of work from code behind, please help me.

Comment: The easiest way is to set the `AutoGenerated` columns to true and make sure your dataset contains just the columns you want.

Comment: Yes this is the easiest way but I want to do some changes on run time in data which is coming from database, that is why I need it to do it dynamically in my code behind file.

Comment: If you really want to manipulate that much data it may be easier to use a ListView instead of a GridView.